# How to assign domain to subfolder in aws ec2 Linux Ami Instance?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, dns

I have Linux Ami instance on ec2. I have two projects hosted on it. See the image.
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRQdH.png)

I have successfully assigned a domain to wordpress but in my domain i have to hit this link -> www.criccentral.com/wordpress

If I put all the files of the wordpress outside then I have to hit this link -> www.criccentral.com

But i want my wordpress files to be in the subfolder as shown in the image and i should hit link -> www.criccentral.com

How could I do this? I want to do it without route 53. 
If there is no way to do without route 53 then tell me the route 53 method

I am new to AWS so guide me in easy way! THANKS

Comment: You can't do this via Route53. Route53 is a DNS service and DNS only deals with looking up server names and translating those to IP addresses. DNS does not deal with the path portion of a request. What you are trying to do is a function of the web server software (Apache?) that you are running on your server, and the fact that you are running on AWS isn't really relevant.

Comment: i understand you but a little bit. Please guide me how we can do this?
I guess changing httpd.conf file.... something like that?

Actually i want to assign domain to subfolder. Tell me how it is possible in aws ec2 instance (Amazon Linux Ami)

Comment: @MarkB  i am waiting for your response with solution

Comment: Stop searching for how to do this on AWS Linux and instead search for the method to do this with Apache Web Server.

Comment: ok THanks @MarkB

Comment: @MarkB Sir i am trying to search out for this but it seems to be complicated to me.
Can you refer me some good links? i am just a beginner

Comment: I think you just need to change the document root setting in your Apache config, but I'm not an Apache expert. If you deleted this question and asked a new question about Apache you would attract the people that actually know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully got an answer on this site

**Link**

http://brianshim.com/webtricks/host-multiple-sites-amazon-ec2/